# Find the closest timestamp (from a array of dictionaries) to a given timestamp

Tags: python, date, dictionary

Having the following list of dictionaries, which includes a timestamp (in string value) and a value:

```
my_example = [{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}]
```

I want for a given timestamp value (in string format), find the closest value.

This means that:

- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:02Z` I want to return: `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}`
- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:04Z` I want to return: `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}`
- If the given_timestamp is `2009-11-10T23:00:15Z` I want to return: `{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:15Z', 'value': 3}`
  etc.

Can someone give me a hand?

I know there's a built-in function that makes this magic for a list of integers, for example, but I dont know how to make it work with dates:

`min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber))`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: closest value based on what ?

Comment: Based on the input/given timestamp. Check the example.

Comment: How is the value parameter changing ?

Comment: Its just an example to understand the issue.

Comment: "f the given_timestamp is 2009-11-10T23:00:15Z I want to return: {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:15Z', 'value': 3}" but 00:15 is not in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime` to convert string to datetime object and the use `min`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
my_example = [{'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:01Z', 'value': 1}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:05Z', 'value': 2}, {'timestamp': '2009-11-10T23:00:20Z', 'value': 3}]

myNumber = "2009-11-10T23:00:02Z"
myNumber = datetime.datetime.strptime(myNumber, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
print(min(my_example, key=lambda x:abs(datetime.datetime.strptime(x["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") - myNumber)))
```

Comment: it seems the OP is unclear what he wants out of the question

Comment: The question is totally clear, and the answer is even more clear. Thanks, Rakesh :)

Comment: it's possible to do that in `log(n)` complexity with `bisect` but that's more work